# Make an entire div clickable to the_permalink();

Tags: php, wordpress, hyperlink

I have the following code:

```
<div class="carousel-caption">
     <div class="carousel-caption-inner">
          <p class="carousel-caption-title" data-postid="<?php the_ID(); ?>" data-excerpt="<?php echo esc_html( get_the_excerpt() ); ?>" data-published="<?php echo get_the_date(); ?>"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></p>
          <p class="carousel-caption-category"><?php echo get_the_category_list( ', ' ); ?></p>
    </div>
</div>
```

This ( with some more PHP lines ) turns out into this :

[image: check img]

What I need is to have that white box clickable and it should send to the post link/article.

I tried adding

```
<div onclick="window.open('newurl.html','mywindow');" style="cursor: pointer;">&nbsp;</div>
```

but it didn't work, or I did something wrong.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix it myself.

This is how I solved it. ( i found this method somewhere, I did not invent it :D )

```
<div class="carousel-caption container1">
  <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><span class="link-spanner"></span></a>
    <div class="carousel-caption-inner">
       <p class="carousel-caption-title" data-postid="<?php the_ID(); ?>" data-excerpt="<?php echo esc_html( get_the_excerpt() ); ?>" data-published="<?php echo get_the_date(); ?>"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></p>
        <p class="carousel-caption-category"><?php echo get_the_category_list( ', ' ); ?></p>
    </div>
</div>
```

As you can see, I added this code below the div I wanted to make it clickable

```
<a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><span class="link-spanner"></span></a>
```

Then using this CSS:

```
.container1{
   position:absolute;
}

.link-spanner {
   position:absolute; 
   width:100%;
   height:100%;
   top:0;
   left: 0;
   z-index: 1;
 }
```

It made my white area become clickable and it takes me to the post link.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap the inner div in an anchor element to turn it into a link, and remove the anchor that's currently wrapping the title.

This is valid in HTML5.

```
<div class="carousel-caption">
  <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
    <div class="carousel-caption-inner">
      <p class="carousel-caption-title" data-postid="<?php the_ID(); ?>" data-excerpt="<?php echo esc_html( get_the_excerpt() ); ?>" data-published="<?php echo get_the_date(); ?>">
        <?php the_title(); ?>
      </p>
      <p class="carousel-caption-category"><?php echo get_the_category_list( ', ' ); ?></p>
    </div>
  </a>
</div>
```

Comment: It does not work as the class "carousel-caption-inner" has css on it which is how that white box is created.  " .carousel-caption-inner {
    background: #fff; padding: 30px 40px !important; } "

Comment: the class `carousel-caption-inner` is not removed